UE5 Crashing Only During Perforce Sync
I'm dealing with a really frustrating issue with Unreal Engine 5. For the past three days, every time I start UE5 and perform a sync with the plugin Perforce, the engine crashes. Here are the details from the crash report:

Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION 0x000000070003cfd0
UnrealEditor_Engine!UMaterialInterface::PrecacheDefaultMaterialPSOs()
[D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\Materials\Material.cpp:611]
UnrealEditor_Engine!FGlobalComponentRecreateRenderStateContext::~FGlobalComponentRecreateRenderStateContext()
[D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\Components\ActorComponent.cpp:362]
UnrealEditor_Engine!UMaterial::PostEditChangePropertyInternal()
[D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\Materials\Material.cpp:4755]
...

Steps I've Taken So Far:
Cleared Derived Data Cache: I’ve cleared the DerivedDataCache folder to ensure there are no corrupt cache files.
Disabled Non-Essential Plugins: I have disabled all non-essential plugins to rule out plugin conflicts.
Reduced Graphics Settings: Lowered the graphics and mesh quality settings to reduce system load.
Updated Drivers: Ensured that my graphics drivers are up-to-date (using NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080).
Checked Material Settings: Ensured default materials are not corrupted and simplified complex materials.
Additional Observations:
The crash only occurs when I perform a sync from Perforce.  Disabling source control plugins hasn't resolved the issue.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I'm looking for any suggestions or solutions that might help resolve this issue. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Have you tried syncing from Perforce directly (e.g. "Get Latest" in P4V or p4 sync at the command line)?  Maybe there's some sort of error condition that the UE plugin doesn't know how to handle.

Yeah, it's working when i "get latest" from p4v and UE is open. I think the problem come from the plugin at the moment.
